Inverse Z Transform of $\frac{1}{(z-a)^2}$
I'm Trying to find the Z-transform of $$\frac{1}{(z-a)^2}$$ in discrete, i.e using $u[n]$.
Using the known transformation of:
$$n \cdot \alpha^n \cdot u[n]  \Longleftrightarrow \frac{\alpha \cdot z^{-1}}{(1-\alpha \cdot z^{-1})^2} = \frac{\alpha \cdot z}{(z-\alpha)^2}$$
I'm getting
$$z^{-1}\left\{z^{-1} \cdot \frac{z}{(z-a)^2}\right\} \Rightarrow \text{Time shift by } -1 \Rightarrow (n-1) \cdot a^{(n-1)} \cdot u[n-1]$$
which according to Wolfram Alpha is wrong, apparently the answer is $$(n-1) \cdot a^{(n-2)} \cdot u[n-1]$$
from which I have not been able to understand why $a^{(n-2)}$ rather than $a^{(n-1)}$.
would appreciate some help.

I think you're missing an $\alpha$ on your third line.
Specifically, if you know that
$$n \cdot \alpha^n \cdot u[n]  \Longleftrightarrow \frac{\alpha \cdot z^{-1}}{(1-\alpha \cdot z^{-1})^2} = \frac{\alpha \cdot z}{(z-\alpha)^2},$$ then
$$\frac{1}{(z-a)^2} = \alpha ^{-1} z^{-1}\cdot \frac{\alpha z}{(z-a)^2}\Rightarrow \alpha^{-1}\text{Time shift by } -1 \Rightarrow (n-1) \cdot a^{(n-2)} \cdot u[n-1].$$
